# mysql insert multiple column data to one column

Tags: mysql, insert, left-join

Hi I have mysql query like this

```
Select  postid, user_id , qfav.userid, qfeed.userid, qview.userid  
from post_words as qw 
left join (Select userid, postid as postidfav  from post_favorite) as  qfav 
    on qfav.questidfav=qw.questid 
left join (Select userid, questid as questidfeed from post_feedback) as  qfeed 
    on qfeed.questidfeed=qw.questid 
left join (Select userid, questid as questidview from post_stats_view) as qview 
    on qview.questidview=qw.questid 
where qw.word='stackoverflow';
```

Result

```
questid user_id  userid  userid userid

 100       4       3      null    5
  25       1       4       8      6
 200       76      7       21     23
```

How i can insert column values to another table one column like

```
userids
   4
   3
   null
   5
   1
   4
   8
   6
  76
   7
  21
  23
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's make the query a little more standard by getting rid of all the unnecessary sub-queries:

```
Select  postid, user_id , qfav.userid, qfeed.userid, qview.userid  
from post_words as qw 
left join post_favorite as qfav 
    on qfav.questidfav=qw.questid 
left join post_feedback as qfeed
    on qfeed.questidfeed=qw.questid 
left join post_stats_view as qview
    on qview.questidview=qw.questid 
where qw.word='stackoverflow';
```

Then we will bring all the `userid` columns into a single column using `UNION` and prepend an INSERT onto the front:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (userid) 
Select  userid
  from post_words as qw 
  where qw.word='stackoverflow'
UNION
Select  qfav.userid
  from post_words as qw 
  left join post_favorite as qfav 
    on qfav.questidfav=qw.questid 
  where qw.word='stackoverflow'
UNION
Select  qfeed.userid
  from post_words as qw 
  left join post_feedback as qfeed
    on qfeed.questidfeed=qw.questid 
  where qw.word='stackoverflow'
UNION
  Select  qview.userid  
  from post_words as qw 
  left join post_stats_view as qview
    on qview.questidview=qw.questid 
  where qw.word='stackoverflow';
```

There's probably some way to avoid having to do the `qw.word='stackoverflow'` 4 times, but no inspiration is hitting me right now...

Make sure your `SomeTable` doesn't require a unique `user_id` column.

Note also you've been a bit inconsistent in `user_id` vs `userid` - I started to clean that up and then realized it may actually be in your tables, so you may have to do a little cleaning of my cleaning.